# How to handle the following parenthesized expression

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73508143/how-to-disambiguate-a-subselect-from-a-parenthesized-expression) I'm wondering what the correct way to deal with the following race condition between whether an expression is a subselect or a parenthesized expression:

```
grammar Subselect;
statement: query EOF;
query
    : select
    | query 'UNION' query
    ;

select: 'SELECT' expr (',' expr)*;

expr
    : '1'                          # identifier
    | '(' expr ')'                 # parenExpr
    | '(' query ')'                # subSelect
    ;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

And from running `SELECT ((SELECT 1))` I get:

[image]

What would be a suggested way to deal with this? (Note: the grammar above is a tremendous simplification and the select clause has many more components of it, but this is the simplest example I could use to show the issue that seems a bit insoluble to me with antlr4 -- hopefully an expert can help me solve it though!)

Comment: This grammar is ambiguous, to be sure. But Antlr4 parses it correctly anyway, no? I mean, you get the expected parse tree. Perhaps the ambiguity causes a slight inefficiency in the parse, but it's hardly a common usage. So, unless it actually causes a problem, the suggested way to deal with this would be "don't worry about it". (Also, it's an ambiguity, not a "race condition". A race condition is when two processes concurrently access the same memory location without locking and at least one modifies the data in that location. Antlr does not parallelise parsing, afaik.)

Comment: FWIW, I think that multiply parenthesised selects are not accepted by all SQL parsers.

Comment: @rici what would be a way to modify the grammar to not accept multiply-parenthesized selects? I think I'd want to take that approach actually.

Comment: I'd have to see more of your grammar to even have a chance of making a sensible suggestion. Actually, I'm not sure about my last comment; I remember hitting an error like that once,  but I don't entirely trust my memory any more :-)

Comment: @rici I see, yea I tried a ton of different ways to do indirection and any ones that I had that I thought would 'work' were giving me left-recursion errors in antlr, probably due to the missing `(` token before `expr`. In the previous question I. gave a bit more of the grammar if that gives you enough to work with -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73508143/how-to-disambiguate-a-subselect-from-a-parenthesized-expression

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want to achieve (solving the ambiquity doesn't give you much advantage), but to deal with that anyway: why do you use the same definition of an input sequence twice, in the first place? You could write:

```
grammar Subselect;
statement: query EOF;
query
    : select
    ;

select: select_clause;
select_clause: 'SELECT' expr (',' expr)*;

expr
    : '1'                          # identifier
    | '(' expr ')'                 # parenExpr
    | '(' query ')'                # subSelect
    ;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

This will allow only one pair of parentheses around a select statement.

Comment: I've modified the `query` rule in the question so it's more explicit -- basically that form allows having a set-operation at the top level, such as `SELECT ((SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 1))`.

Comment: any feedback on the update?

Comment: Oh that was an additional question? Sorry, I didn't see it as that, but just a comment. The query as it is now is even worse. It allows UNION for all query types, while it is only allowed for SELECT. I have given a possible solution in my answer. If that's not what you want then let me know.

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean for "all query type" ? Do you mean something like a `DELETE` or `ALTER` or something else? But yes, as it is now, our syntax only supports `SELECT` so it's a bit of a moot point wrt the question.